# How can I use a custom JList renderer's results outside of a JList?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlist, listcellrenderer

I have a custom renderer that works just perfectly - how can I use it as a "drawing engine" to produce the same objects it would produce in a JList?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want.  Can you show some code or provide an example as to how you want to use the results of the renderer?  Are you trying to use the renderer to display the components in some other component (like a JPanel)?

Comment: I would be putting them like icons or images in a JPanel. Is this possible?

Comment: Use JLabel for that. That's pretty much what its for.

Comment: Yes but how can I grab the render from the custom renderer (extends from ListCellRenderer) to put in the JLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `ListCellRenderer`, simply invoke [`getListCellRendererComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JList,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) with the appropriate values, and then invoke `setBounds(x, y, w, h)` and `paint(g)` on the returned component (which is all normal cases is the renderer itself) to paint it as it would be in a list.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I use it as a "drawing engine" to produce the same objects it
>   would produce in a JList?

AFAIK

- [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) is only illusion, painting factory betweens value stored in `XxxModel` and `View`
- `Renderer`  is implemented for `JList` (then for `JComboBox` too), `JTree` and `JTable` (now we can forgot for `JTreeTable` and its custom derivates)
- for rest of `Swing JComponents` you have to use standard paint, more informations, wroking code examples in official Oracle tutorials

Comment: Can you expand on this please? I don't understand. "Renderer is only illusion, painting factory betweens value stored in XxxModel and View"

Comment: Swing team decided that these component showing its value stored in XxxModel by implemets Renderer concept are only rendered (by using implemented DefaultXxxRenderer in APIs) by default, you can to override this Renderer

Comment: @tM--, as mKobel has mentioned, we use a render-er just to tell how the cell of `JList` or `JTable` should be rendered by passing it a component: `hi list! to nicer view, render your cell with model data just like this label i am giving you`.

Comment: @mKorbel, +1 A direct link of the official link could be given. :)